# Laravel5: TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 3123:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**THE SITUATION:**

Sorry in advance if it has already been asked. But no matter what I can never make it works.

I am using Laravel 5 as API.

I have a simple function to edit a task.

I am testing it through my web app or through Postman.

I am always getting this error:

```
TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 3123:
```

[image: TokenMismatchException]

**THE CODE:**

**The function:**

```
public function updateTask(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->name = $request->input('name');
    $task->type = $request->input('type');
    $task->save();

    return $task;
}
```

**The route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::post('update', 'TaskController@updateTask');
});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why I am getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by inserting the route name as an item in the array $except in the file:

```
app/http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

Like this:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $except = [

     'update'
 ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am using Laravel as an API.. My form is angular.. So I have no idea where to get the csrf_token() from..

Answer (score 2):

It works from your web app because your web app is passing the token.

You need to open up `app/Http/Kernel.php` and comment out `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`.  However this will leave your site vulnerable to CSRF attacks so you should also find another way to protect your site.

My suggestion would be to keep the CSRF middleware and create a new route group with a prefix of your choice ( usually something like `api/v1/` ) which is outside the `web` middleware group.  These routes would then not be protected by CSRF so you should find another way to protect them.  I've recently had a lot of success doing this exact same thing with `jwt-auth`.  https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Of course, if your front end is not completely decoupled with your backend and Laravel is outputting the initial page which is then later controlled by angular, you can drop the CSRF token into a meta tag and grab it later with angular and pass it in the header `X-CSRF-TOKEN`, then Laravel will pick it up.

Comment: But my route (attempt 1) should work no? Is outside the middleware so there is control of tokens no? But it doesn't work

Comment: Is your route inside a route group and does that route group have the `web` middleware?

Comment: I try all the possibilities: 1 Outside the middleware. 2 with the web middleware. 3 with the api middleware. But never worked..

Comment: And replying to your last paragraph: The web app is completely separated from the API

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass this in your headers;

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': {{ csrf_token() }}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And

```
php artisan key:generate
```